Symfony 6.4 authenticate programatically problem
I have a very weird problem in Symfony 6.4 when I try to authenticate a new user programatically using a route that looks like this:
#[Route("/test-user")]
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $email = 'user' . uniqid() . '@example.com';

    $user = new User();
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $hashedPassword = $this->passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, 'AnythingToPass123');
    $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();

    $this->security->login($user);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('default_index'));
}

The new user wouldn't authenticate at all, and I'll get redirected to the login page. The strange thing is that if I type there the email/password, it will work!
I tried with an existing user and it also works:
#[Route("/test-user")]
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->userManager->getUserByEmail('existinguser@gmail.com');

    $this->security->login($user);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('default_index'));
}

Am I missing something when creating a new user?

Does your log contain any information about this? Or the profiler?

Not really, I tried to catch the issue using the profiler but it just tells me that the user is not authenticated.
I am starting to think that it has to do with the $request and its session. Probably you cannot just create and authenticate at the same time.

If a redirect happens, then the profiler also knows about this. Have a look at "Last 10" (at the top left of the profiler) to find an earlier request

Thanks for that tip, it kinda shows that the request/session is not instantly updated. So I'll create an intermediate page to authenticate. Thanks!
